# How can I call images from database to Lightbox Jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, lightbox

Is there a way to call images from my database to my lightbox jquery. I want to call lots of pictures to my picture gallery:

```
<%--using multiple="" images="" in="" a="" sequence="", link="" is="" thumbnail=""of="" image--=""%>

          <div>
            Birds<br /><br />

            <a href="images/AmericanGoldfinch_male.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip2]" 
            title="American Goldfinch">
              <img src="images/AmericanGoldfinch_male.JPG" width="60" height="60" 
              alt="" />
           </a>

             <a href="images/birdgroup1.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip2]" 
            title="Mixed Birds">
              <img src="images/birdgroup1.JPG" width="60" height="60" alt="" />
            </a> 
            <a href="images/doves.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip2]" 
            title="Mourning Doves">
              <img src="images/doves.JPG" width="60" height="60" alt="" />
            </a>
            <a href="images/goldfinch_fiesta.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip2]" 
            title="American Goldfinches">
              <img src="images/goldfinch_fiesta.JPG" width="60" height="60" alt="" />
            </a>

            <a href="images/hummingbird.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip2]" 
            title="Ruby Throated Hummingbird">
              <img src="images/hummingbird.JPG" width="60" height="60" alt="" />
            </a>

            <a href="images/RoseBreastedGrosbeak_male.jpg" 
            rel="lightbox[roadtrip2]" 
            title="Rose Breasted Grosbeak">
              <img src="images/RoseBreastedGrosbeak_male.JPG" width="60"                   height="60" alt="" />
            </a>

         </div>
        </form>
 </body>
```

What will I put to my query?

Comment: How you storing images into your database ? Just path or whole image as byte[].  IF storing as path and then just create a function looping path value and set lightbox structure format html, and it you storing as  byte[]  then go for HTTP handler

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using an HTTP handler, like this:

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler 
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Grab ID from query string
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["roomID"]);

        // Logic here to retrieve image from database

        // Write image to context object to return to browser

        // Set content type to type of image, change to whatever you need it to be
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
    }

    public bool IsReusable 
    {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your client code you can call the HTTP handler, like this:

```
<img src="ImageHandler.ashx?id=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the images in the view are just references to image resources like that:

```
images/AmericanGoldfinch_male.jpg
```

then you can loop through your database records to emit the markup for the images.  For example, let's assume on your model you have populated an `IEnumerable<SomeCustomObject>` called `Images` with the URLs and titles of the image files.  In that case your view would contain something like this:

```
<div>
    Birds<br /><br />

    @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
    {
    <a href="@image.Url" rel="lightbox[roadtrip2]" title="@image.Title">
        <img src="@image.Url" width="60" height="60" alt="" />
    </a>
    }
</div>
```

This would generate the same markup as you have manually created, but dynamically for all of the images in the model.

The next question then becomes... Are the images referenced by URL from the database or are they actually *stored* in the database?  If the latter, then what you'd probably do is create a separate action method to act as the "image" itself, which dynamically returns the image from the database.  First you'd have to change the above code to use that action.  Something like this, assuming an image ID instead of a URL on the model:

```
<div>
    Birds<br /><br />

    @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
    {
    <a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = image.ID })" rel="lightbox[roadtrip2]" title="@image.Title">
        <img src="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = image.ID })" width="60" height="60" alt="" />
    </a>
    }
</div>
```

The difference now is that instead of using a static URL for the image, you dynamically create one based on the action name, controller name, and ID of the image as a route value.  Next you'd need to create the action method.  If the image is just a `byte[]` from your data access layer, then you can just have that action return a `File` result.  Something like this:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(int id)
{
    var file = Files.Get(id); // this would be replaced with however you get your file from the database
    return File(file.Data, file.ContentType, file.Name);
}
```

This is assuming, of course, that you also store a name and content type with the files in the database.  If you're storing the raw file data in the database itself then it's a very good idea to at least store its content type as well.